# Find specific file's full path with for loop

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file, I am stuck in the middle of a search loop:

```
FOR /R %MapDirectory% %%s IN ("%FullName%") DO SET DesiredMapFilePath=%%s
```

What I want to do is to find the full path to a file given by its file from the given root directory in all its sub-directories. It is guaranteed that there is only one file with the given name.

`%MapDirectory%` is the root path (e. g.: `%~dp0\some\directory\wanna\start\from`) and `%FullName%` is the full name of the file I am looking for (e. g.: `foo.txt`).

The above command line gives fails to find the given file which actually exists in a sub-directory of the given root path (`%MapDirectory%`).

Comment: `for` (`/R`) does not access the file system unless there are wildcards, so the easiest way is to use `dir /B` (`/S`) and parse its output by `for /F`...

Comment: Thank aschipfi! Didn't know /r only works for wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine with the dir command

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%s IN ('dir /b /s "%MapDirectory%\%FullName%"') DO (set DesiredMapFilePath=%%s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will test with your sample tmr. (Living in diff timezone) but for now, one curiosity, %MapDirectory%\%FullName% gives me wonder, it looks like searching files from current dir, not its sub...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided you could use the `Where` command.

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%s In (
    'Where/R "%~dp0some\directory\wanna\start\from" "foo.txt"'
) Do Set "DesiredMapFilePath=%%s"
```

**[EDIT /]**

The Where command structure above and below does not work if you have a trailing backslash in your starting directory. *(but your question did not have one and neither did my answer)*.

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%s In ('Where/R "%MapDirectory%" "foo.txt"'
    ) Do Set "DesiredMapFilePath=%%s"
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Will test it tmr. I was try with where keyword in prev but nothing works for me that time. Does it works for win8 too?

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason why Windows 8 should not run this code correctly.

Comment: I did test with your sample code but didn't work for me, it still failed to find foo.txt starts from \from to its sub-directory for some reason. Anyway, above sample works for me and thanks for your comment!

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with the code snippet I have provided it works, I use the same code often and prefer it over the `dir` version you have opted for. I am appending another version of it to match the structure used in Richrd's version.